# Equation For Multiples

Tags: recreational-mathematics, education

So this is probably a super easy question for Math Stack Exchangers. Anyways I can determine the multiples of 3 up to 10 doing this.

**multiples of 3 up to 10**

```
0*3 = 0
1*3 = 3 
2*3 = 6
3*3 = 9
```

What would this look like as an equation? Like I said this is in my opinion a very elementary approach and I would like to learn a more advanced way of doing this using proper terminology. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

*FYI, this probably will need to be re-tagged as I have no idea how to even tag this question, so I am going to just guess.*

Answer (score 2):

The nonnegative multiples of $3$ have the form $3n$ for [natural](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_number) $n$. If you want to write the [set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28mathematics%29#Definition) of all of these multiples of $3$ with notation rather than words, you can write $\{3n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$. If you want to write the set of these multiples of $3$ that are less than $10$, you can write something like $\{3n\mid n\in\mathbb N,n<10/3\}$.

You said "as an equation", but [an equation is something with an equals sign](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation), and there aren't really any natural things to write with an equals sign to describe this collection of numbers.

Comment: Technically, $x(x-3)(x-6)(x-9) = 0$ would be an equation with solutions $x \in \{0,3,6,9\}$, but I don't see it as something useful here.